# Двумерный массив, задача. Помогите разобраться

Tags: java

Дан двумерный массив N*N, который содержит несколько прямоугольников.
Различные прямоугольники не соприкасаются и не накладываются.
Внутри прямоугольник весь заполнен 1-ками.
В массиве:

1) a[i, j] = 1, если элемент (i, j) принадлежит какому-либо прямоугольнику

2) a[i, j] = 0, в противном случае. `getRectangleCount` должен возвращать количество прямоугольников.

Метод `main` не участвует в тестировании:

```
public class ArrayWithRectsGetThemCount21032016 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[][] a = new byte[][]{
                {1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 1}
        };
        int count = getRectangleCount(a);
        System.out.println("count = " + count + ". Должно быть 2");
    }
    public static int getRectangleCount(byte[][] a) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень интересно. Расскажите, пожалуйста, чего Вы уже добились помимо `return 0;`.

Comment: Пока ничего...)

Comment: Хм, ну какие-то мысли у Вас есть? Вот начинаете Вы в цикле проверять элементы массива, и встречается Вам единица ..?

Comment: если найдем единицу, значит найдем начало прямоугольника, а как определить его границы и исключить найденный прямоугольник из поиска ?

Comment: ... идем дальше по этой строке. Где-то единицы (или строка) должны кончится - значит мы нашли ширину этого прямоугольника. Давайте, давайте, что же из Вас каждое слово надо вытаскивать?

Comment: .. следовательно потом мы ищем длину прямоугольника а потом следующий прямоугольник и так далее) спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: можно еще завести другой массив того же размера и там как-то отмечать уже обследованные области (как в морском бое). Нашли ширину и высоту прямоугольника - отметили его как обследованный.

Comment: На JavaRush есть свой форум для помощи по задачам курса: help.javarush.ru. Вы пробовали туда обратиться? Хотя там нельзя получить полностью сделанное за вас решение, придется хоть что-то сделать самому.

Comment: Спасибо, но это задача не с JavaRush поєтому я туда не обращался

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача довольно несложная. Метод - делаем почти также, как если бы делали на листочке:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[][] a = new byte[][]{
            {1, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 0, 1}
    };
    int count = getRectangleCount(a);
    System.out.println("count = " + count + ". Должно быть 2");
}
public static int getRectangleCount(byte[][] a) {
    int count = 0, tmp = -1, jt = a[0].length;
    boolean findRect = false;
    while (tmp != count) { //если счётчик увеличился за проход по матрице - снова делаем проход по матрице
        tmp = count;

        outerloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] == 1 && !findRect) { //случай, когда встретили прямоугольник
                    count++;
                    jt = j; //запоминаем столбец, в котором начался прямоугольник
                    findRect = true;
                    a[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if (a[i][j] == 1 && findRect) {//обнуляем, чтобы не мешался
                    a[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if (a[i][j] == 0 && findRect && j == jt) { //если элемент под прямоугольник равен 0 - он закончился
                    break outerloop; //выходим из внешнего цикла
                }
                else if (a[i][j] == 0 && findRect && j > jt) { //если элемент справа от прямоугольника равен 0 - идем на след строку
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        findRect = false;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Вывод** программы:

> count = 2. Должно быть 2

¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

Answer (score 0):

В решении выше закралась ошибка: если к примеру матрица будет выглядеть так:

```
byte[][] a2 = new byte[][]{
                {1, 0, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 0, 1}
```

По вашему решению он все равно покажет 2 прямоугольника, хотя в действительности их 3.

Подсмотрел идею в вашем решении и реализовал метод, который корректно посчитает все прямоугольники:

```
public static int getRectangleCount(byte[][] a) {
        int indexStopX = -1, indexStartX = -1;
        int count = 0, tmpCount = -1;
        boolean findRect = false;

/*        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();*/


        while (count != tmpCount) {

            tmpCount = count;

            otherloop:
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                    if (a[i][j] == 1 && !findRect){
                        count++;
                        findRect = true;
                        a[i][j] = 0;
                        indexStopX = j;
                        indexStartX = j;
                    }

                    else if (a[i][j] == 1 && findRect && j >= indexStartX){
                        a[i][j] = 0;
                    }

                    else if (a[i][j] == 0 && j == indexStopX){
                        break otherloop;
                    }

                    else if (a[i][j] == 0 && findRect && j > indexStopX){
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
            findRect = false;
            indexStopX = -1;
            indexStartX = -1;

/*            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();*/

        }

        return count;
    }
```

Если убрать закомментированный код, то можно увидеть как изменяется исходная матрица после нахождения соответствующего прямоугольника.